# How to put a 1 px wide black border around the outer most edge of all layers in a Photoshop document?

Tags: photoshop, layer, after-effects

I'm separating an image into various layers in Photoshop to be used by After Effects.  The layers have different amounts of transparent pixels.  Apparently, transparent pixels can change the size of a layer and this confuses AE.  For example, scale by a percentage can differ for each layer.

What solves the problem is to put black corners in all the layers.  What I thought would be simpler would be to put a 1 px wide black border around all the layers as defined by the original image.

Can someone think of an easy way to do this?  I'm splitting an image into 5 to 10 layers and would like to be able to do this by selecting all the layers and say "make a 1px wide border".

Comment: You can get layer bounds with `layer.bounds` then, for example, create an layer with a rectangle of that size with fill == 0 and apply stroke, then maybe merge the rectangle with the layer if you want. Et voilà

Comment: Or just increase the _canvas size_ by 2 pixels in x and y